# Cant call delegate method from my protocol class

Tags: ios, objective-c, adapter, delegation

I have a protocol in one class:

```
@protocol DataStorageManager

- (void) saveFile;

@end

@interface DataManager : NSObject
{
    id <DataStorageManager> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DataStorageManager> delegate;

//methods

@end
```

and its implementation:

```
@implementation DataManager

@synthesize delegate;

@end
```

and I have another class which is the adapter between the first and the third one:

```
#import "DataManager.h"
#import "DataPlistManager.h"

@interface DataAdapter : NSObject <DataStorageManager>

@property (nonatomic,strong) DataPlistManager *plistManager;
- (void) saveFile;

@end
```

and its implementation

```
#import "DataAdapter.h"

@implementation DataAdapter

-(id) initWithDataPlistManager:(DataPlistManager *) manager
{
    self = [super init];
    self.plistManager = manager;
    return self;
}

- (void) saveFile
{
    [self.plistManager savePlist];
}

@end
```

So when I in first method try to call my delegate method like this

```
[delegate saveFile];
```

Nothing happened. I don't understand what's wrong with the realization - it's a simple adapter pattern realization. So I need to use the delegate which will call the methods from the third class. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the `delegate` property. You need to do this,

```
-(id) initWithDataPlistManager:(DataPlistManager *) manager
{
    self = [super init];
    self.plistManager = manager;
    self.plistManager.delegate = self;
    return self;
}
```

Also, in `DataManager` class remove the ivar declaration, just declaring property is sufficient, the ivar gets automatically created. Call the delegate method as below,

```
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(saveFile)] {
    [self.delegate saveFile]; 
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: now there is an error _Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'DataPlistManager *'_  What's wrong now?

Comment: @ShurupuS Are you sure you want to pass `DataPlistManager` instance in  `initWithDataPlistManager:` method or should it be `DataManager` instance instead?

Comment: What is `DataPlistManager` class anyways? Should it be subclass of `DataManager` class?

Comment: @Aamar DataPlistManager is just a class which contain some methods for work with plist. I try to use the adapter pattern - the main idea that I can easily change the class for working with different formats of files (DataPlistManager) without many changes in code. So in adapter I should call the methods from DataPlistManager. Sorry, I'm the new one in iOS dev and may be my description isn't complete.

Comment: @ShurupuS So in the above code, you expect `DataPlistManager` to call the delegate method which is implemented by `DataAdapter`? If that is the case, I think `DataPlistManager` should be subclass of `DataManager`.

Comment: Ohhh... I totally confused with this case.. As I see `DataManager` will take somehow `DataStorageManager` which is a `DataAdapter` and  `Data Adaptor` will use tghe present DataPlistManager class for all the next work with plist file.. That's how I would like to use all this construction.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36907/discussion-between-shurupus-and-amar)

Comment: @ShurupuS Then in that case, in your `DataManager` class, you need to write something like this:: `self.delegate=adapterInstance`, this will make the `DataAdapter` instance the delegate, as required. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you forget to set your protocol delegate and also need to call protocol method
by `self.delegate....`

I just Give Basic Idea for how to Create **Protocol**

[Also Read This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

```
#DetailViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MasterDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) getButtonTitile:(NSString *)btnTitle;
@end


@interface DetailViewController : MasterViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MasterDelegate> customDelegate; 

#DetailViewController.m

if([self.customDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(getButtonTitile:)])
{
          [self.customDelegate getButtonTitile:button.currentTitle];    
}

#MasterViewController.m

create obj of DetailViewController

DetailViewController *obj = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
obj.customDelegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reportTypeVC animated:YES];

and add delegate method in MasterViewController.m for get button title.

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Custom Delegate  Method

-(void) getButtonTitile:(NSString *)btnTitle;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", btnTitle);

}
```