# Property 'delegate' not found in object of type exception when trying to use delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

can't understand what's wrong in this case, so I cant use the delegate - there is an exception in `self.plistManager.delegate = self;` `Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'DataPlistManager *'`

```
#import "DataManager.h"
#import "DataPlistManager.h"

@interface DataAdapter : NSObject <DataStorageManager>

@property (nonatomic,strong) DataPlistManager *plistManager;
- (void) saveFile;

@end
```

and its implementation

```
#import "DataAdapter.h"

@implementation DataAdapter

-(id) initWithDataPlistManager:(DataPlistManager *) manager
{
    self = [super init];
    self.plistManager = manager;
    self.plistManager.delegate = self;
    return self;
}

- (void) saveFile
{
    [self.plistManager savePlist];
}

@end
```

Comment: Does `DataPlistManager` declare a `delegate` property?

Comment: In `DataAdapter.h` write reference for the class, using `@class DataPlistManager` before this line `@interface DataAdapter : NSObject <DataStorageManager>`

Comment: Show the declaration for `DataPlistManager`.

Comment: Hi, please look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636874/cant-call-delegate-method-from-my-protocol-class this is the parent of this question, can't understand how should I set the delegate in this case. Of course there is no property declaration in DataPlistManager because I think that there is no need for this. But the recommendation from the previous answer was to add this line and now there is an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your DataPlistManager needs a property delegate:

```
@property (weak) id<DataStorageManager> delegate;
```

Comment: `retain`?   I don't think so.  `unsafe_unretained` I reckon.  Anyway the OP is using ARC!

Comment: Delegates objects should not be retained so as to avoid retain cycle. It should be weak

Answer (score 0):

If you add `#import "DataAdapter.h"` in your `"DataPlistManager.h"` file then remove it and add it to `"DataPlistManager.m"` file, I don't know but some days ago i have same issue, and i solved it by using this trick :)

Comment: That will slightly speed-up compilation (once you add `@class DataPlistManager`) and nothing more.

Comment: @trojanfoe - really i dont know what is this but i solved my issue by using this way..:( thanks

Answer (score 0):

DataManager class contains delegate property so you should set your object as delegate of DataManager class and call method (send message) saveFile inside delegate class:

```
@implementation DataAdapter

- (void)someMethod) {
    DataManager *dataManagerObject = [[DataManager alloc] init];
    dataManagerObject.delegate = self;
}

@implementation DataManager

- (void)someDelegateMethod {
    [self.delegate saveFile];
}
```

Are you sure you understand concept of delegation pattern?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html